# Overridden c# TabControl OnClick is not called

Tags: c#, visual-studio, overriding, controls

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 and writing in c#.  I have written a descendant of the TabControl class and overridden the OnClick method, then changed my existing TabControl element to use the new class.  Everything compiles and runs, my breakpoint in the constructor is reached, but it's not using the OnClick override!  Here's the TabControl descendant code, thanks in advance for any help!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace LumaSense.Imaging.Calibration.UI
{
    public partial class TabControlModified : TabControl
    {
        public TabControlModified()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private bool superuser;
        public int lastTabSelectedIndex = 0;

        public bool Superuser
        {
            get { return superuser; }
            set { superuser = value; }
        }

        public int LastTabSelectedIndex
        {
            get { return lastTabSelectedIndex; }
            set
            { this.lastTabSelectedIndex = value; }
        }

        protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e)
        {
            // SelectedIndex and tab have already changed before we get here
            if (this.superuser == false)
            {
                if (this.SelectedIndex <= this.lastTabSelectedIndex)
                {
                    this.LastTabSelectedIndex = this.SelectedIndex;
                    base.OnClick(e);
                }
                else
                {
                    base.OnClick(e);
                    this.SelectedIndex = lastTabSelectedIndex;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                this.LastTabSelectedIndex = this.SelectedIndex;
                base.OnClick(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you instantiate this custom tab control, are you adding any pages to the controls? Unless there are any pages, it will not display the tabs which when clicked will trigger than OnClick method.

Answer (score 0):

This snippet works just fine. You need to make sure you have added pages to your tab control in order for the tabs to display and accessible to the user to click.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var mTab = new MyTab();
        mTab.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(100, 100);

        // The OnClick will only work on the 
        // Tabs themselves so Pages must be added to display the Tabs.
        var mtabPage1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TabPage();
        mTab.Controls.Add(mtabPage1);

        this.Controls.Add(mTab);
    }

    class MyTab : TabControl
    {
        protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("I was clicked.");

            base.OnClick(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I found out that using Deselecting and Selecting instead of creating a descendent of TabControl fixed the problem.  Somehow, when using the TabControl descendant, adding the Reactive UI binding of TabControlModified .SelectedIndex messed things up and the overridden OnClick was no longer callerd.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that using Deselecting and Selecting instead of creating a descendent of TabControl fixed the problem. Somehow, when using the TabControl descendant, adding the Reactive UI binding of TabControlModified .SelectedIndex messed things up and the overridden OnClick was no longer callerd.